# cannot change value of scope after running digest cycle in unit test

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, angularjs-digest

I am not able to pass my unit test.  The I am expecting the string to change but keep getting back the original **description**.

In my unit test I was able to mock a attribute change in two ways. I am changing an  **$attribute**

```
<div global-alert description=\"description\"> </div>
```

The attribute is being observed and added to the scope like so ...

```
$attrs.$observe('description', function () {
    $scope.description = $attrs.description;
});
```

**globalAlert** is the name of the directive and **description**  is the attribute that I am changing.

Inside of my unit test I have my spec set up like so

```
 it('should set scope.description to true', function () {
     // 1 mock
    element.attr('description', function () {
        element.attr('description', 'hotDog');
    });

   //2 just recreate the angular.element('<div global-alert description = \"hotDog\"> </div>        
    scope = element.scope();
    element = $compile(html)($rootScope);
    $rootScope.$digest();  // runs in the debugger shows change
    expect(scope.description).to.equal('hotdog');  // equals 'description'
});
```

Description is still set to the original string value on the expect.  The digest is getting hit and a change is shown in the javascript function on my debugger.

**Notice that after the digest in my unit test the value of

```
 $scope.description is "hotDog".
```

[image]

Any help to fix this would be much appreciated

Comment: `element.attr` is called before `element` is assigned.

Comment: I also have it compiled in the beforeEach at the top of all my tests.  I moved element but it didn't matter.